# ODBC connection on 64bit architecture

Tags: architecture, oracle11g, odbc, 32bit-64bit, arcgis

I'm migrating a tool to a 64bit machine for use with Arcmap 9.3.1. Upon execution, it returns the following error - "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application". I'm aware through sleuthing that there exists two versions of the odbcad32.exe; one in the System32 folder, and one in sysWOW64. Oracle 11g connections are already set up such that one should be able to configure either driver in the contrl panel, but upon attempting to configure the necessary driver using the 32 bit version, the very same error occurs. Only the 64 bit tests correctly, but the software uses 32. My question is then - is it possible to point to odbcad32 in the system32 folder, and otherwise, why is it that the ODBC driver might be returning the architecture mismatch error upon configuration in the control panel? I also tried rebuilding the tool source (VB .NET if that matters) in x64 but this did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run / insert using cliconfig in both wow and the standard System32.
Regards
Anthony